# How i change the position more to the left in the navbar-toggler Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I intend to slightly change the navbar-toggler-icon more to the left and their respective menus as well. I have already tried to change the position in the css but this only changes the icon shown in the image and the menus are exactly the same. Could they help me? Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiVcM.jpg

Code of the menu:

```
<a href="#" id="scroll"><span></span></a>
<div class="menu">
    <nav class="navbar container-fluid navbar-expand-lg navbar transparent">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" id="menu_colapso" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><img src="conteudo/menu.png" id="imagem_icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="conteudo/asus.png" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="imagem_logo">
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pr-5 mt-5" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">    <!--mr-auto para voltar ao lado esquerdo-->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="linhaactiva" href="inicio">Início</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="destaques">Destaques</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="museu">Museu</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Urgeiriça</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="historia">Cronologia</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="bairro">Bairro Mineiro</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="minas">As Minas</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="processamento">Processamento</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="ambiental">Impactos Ambientais</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="saude_publica">Saúde Pública</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="recuperacao">Recuperação Ambiental</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mineiros</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="laborais">Condições Laborais</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="impacto_saude">Impacto na Saúde</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="mural">Mural</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Associação</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="fundacao">Fundação</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="objectivos">Objectivos</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="informacoes">Informações </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"> </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">PT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">|</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">EN</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`padding-left:0` is what you're looking for...

- You can do it on the toggler... which moves it left a little (class: pullToLeft)
- You can do it on the nav... which moves it left little more (class: pullNavLeft)
- I replaced the image you had so that I and other people on stack overflow can see the effects in action; working snippet below:

```css
.pullToLeft {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.pullNavLeft {
  padding: .5rem .3rem !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <nav class="navbar container-fluid navbar-expand-lg navbar transparent pullNavLeft">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right pullToLeft" id="menu_colapso" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/favicon.ico" class='img-fluid ' id="imagem_icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="conteudo/asus.png" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="imagem_logo">
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pr-5 mt-5" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <!--mr-auto para voltar ao lado esquerdo-->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="linhaactiva" href="inicio">Início</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="destaques">Destaques</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="museu">Museu</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Urgeiriça</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="historia">Cronologia</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="bairro">Bairro Mineiro</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="minas">As Minas</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="processamento">Processamento</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="ambiental">Impactos Ambientais</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="saude_publica">Saúde Pública</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="recuperacao">Recuperação Ambiental</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mineiros</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="laborais">Condições Laborais</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="impacto_saude">Impacto na Saúde</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="mural">Mural</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Associação</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="fundacao">Fundação</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="objectivos">Objectivos</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="informacoes">Informações </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link"> </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">PT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item2">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">|</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">EN</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).</p>
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <p>Tip: You can also remove the .navbar-expand-md class to ALWAYS hide navbar links and display the toggler button.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it did help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped; you can mark the answer as accepted so that others can benefit from it in the future... https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot!